# Существует ли аналог append в си?

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Хотел узнать насчет того, есть ли какая нибудь функция, которая отправляет переменную в массив(не копирует). Например у меня есть массив строк `char* words[] = {"Lord", "Exame", etc}`
и есть какая нибудь строка `char word[5] = "exit"`. Как можно отправить это слово в массив words, не копируя его туда или не используя библиотеку <string.h>?

Comment: `words[i] = word;`

Comment: массив это тип с фиксированным размером. есть вариант при создании данного массива использовать большой размер сразу. и использовать вспомогательную переменную, в которой хранить количество реальных данных в массиве. *что такое у вас отправляет/не копирует?*